# Learning how to build my own linux kernel

Tags: xen, kernel, linux-kernel

Reference - http://www.linode.com/wiki/index.php/PV-GRUB#Building_Your_Own_Kernel

> In order to work with Xen, a number of options that must be selected:

```
CONFIG_PARAVIRT_GUEST=y
CONFIG_XEN=y
CONFIG_PARAVIRT=y
CONFIG_PARAVIRT_CLOCK=y
CONFIG_XEN_BLKDEV_FRONTEND=y
CONFIG_XEN_NETDEV_FRONTEND=y
CONFIG_HVC_XEN=y
CONFIG_XEN_BALLOON=y
CONFIG_XEN_SCRUB_PAGES=y
```

Where exactly do I specify these configuration?

I have done these steps so far:-

```
wget http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v3.0/linux-3.3.3.tar.bz2
tar -xf linux-3.3.3.tar.bz2
cd linux-3.3.3
make menuconfig
```

`make menuconfig` brings me to the `ncurses` "GUI" but there are so many options I am completely lost....

Any suggestions how I should proceed?

Comment: You can also search for the options with slash followed by option_name inside make menuconfig!  e.g. /CONFIG_XEN will tell you where this option is found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The options in all caps are what gets written into the configuration file for the kernel you will be building (which `make menuconfig` generates).

There are two ways to edit it:

- Open the file and change/add the entries
- Browse to the relevant Xen options through the GUI, and guess their names from the all caps name. Yours will most likely be in `Processor type and features --->`. You can press the help key to see the option's name and description so you can confirm that you are modifying/adding the correct options.

Comment: Yes. Someone on #kernel irc channel just told me to `vim .config` so this solves my problem. Thanks mate!

Comment: You could use the `.config` file as a guide to locate each parameter in the menus, but that would be a lot of extra work.

Comment: Yup, that's a good tip, @DavidSchwartz. Thanks.