# Build your Own Bare bones basic Linux Bootable ISO from Linux Kernel

Tags: linux, kernel, apt, iso, bootable

I am new to kernels. I wish to build my own `custom Bootable Linux ISO image` myself. Can someone please help me with the right steps to do it. There are loads of information but all are distributed and difficult to follow without making errors.

I am seeing this `Linux Kernel source`. I understand I need to build the source, add the `bootloader like Grub`, add `bare basic system packages and file system like GNU C++, make, etc`, and then add an `package manager` like `apt` (Aptitude) before making an `Linux ISO`. I have seen Yokto/Toaster https://www.yoctoproject.org/software-item/toaster/ Project but unsure if I can add my own source files.

Can someone help if there is something like a builder or any tips for steps I need to follow to make an Linux ISO myself? I have been seeing methods to do it online since some time but never got this right. I wish I learnt this by shadowing someone but that may be a selfish wish.

Any help is fine.

Linux: https://www.kernel.org/ and https://github.com/torvalds/linux
Boot loaders: https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/  and https://www.tecmint.com/best-linux-boot-loaders/
Aptitude: https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/aptitude/pr01s04s02.en.html

Docs I have been seeing:

1. [UEFI bootable iso of own Linux distribution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/132359/uefi-bootable-iso-of-own-linux-distribution)
2. [Learning how to build my own linux kernel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37407/learning-how-to-build-my-own-linux-kernel)
3. Yokto [How to easily build your own Linux Distro?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87011/how-to-easily-build-your-own-linux-distro)
4. Toaster https://www.yoctoproject.org/software-item/toaster/

Comment: The System Rescue distro has a repo with a script which does everything you're looking for (excluding building the kernel/grub/etc - but that's a separate question).

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Please put this as a comment. I wish to upvote this answer even if my question was different. How safe is Toaster and their images for security and manipulation https://www.yoctoproject.org/software-item/toaster/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to install the Linux kernel alone?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17122/is-it-possible-to-install-the-linux-kernel-alone)

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I saw yocto/toaster and seems it has prebuild images. Any help with a build script. I am looking like a stupid person asking this again. I am beginner with this process if you get annoyed. Here is what I am trying to achieve: `Linux Kernel` + `Bootloader (Grub)` + `Basic GNU System Utils (not busy box)`. I appreciate your patience.

Comment: @TobySpeight Here is what I am trying to achieve: `Linux Kernel` + `Bootloader (Grub)` + `Basic GNU System Utils (not busybox)`. I am trying to avoid busy box and want the GNU utils. Seems `linux from scratch` uses busybox. Anything that I missing so I use the same scripts and get GNU System utils working? I appreciate your patience.

Comment: I am using `Debian distro` (sometimes Ubuntu desktop for Desktop GUI) right now in my `Windows 11 WSL` and/or secondly as a `VM Machine`. I alternate many times with both